# How to use my custom google calendar module into another custom todo module in Laminas MVC?

Tags: dependency-injection, laminas

I've created a `Calendar module` in `laminas MVC` which interacts with `Google Calendar` and then created another `Todo module` which is supposed to interact with my `Calendar module`. The signature of `CalendarController` in `Calendar module` is like

```
    public function __construct(
        ListProcess $listProcess,
        AddProcess $addProcess,
        EditProcess $editProcess,
        DeleteProcess $deleteProcess
    )
```

Now my code in `Todo module` that is supposed to initiate the scheduling process is as below

```
public function execute(): array
    {
        $todo = json_decode((new CrmApiService())->getTodo($this->getTodoId()), true);
        $eventData["summary"] = $todo->title;
        $eventData["description"] = $todo->content;
        $eventData["startDateTime"] = $todo->nextActionDate;
        $eventData["endDateTime"] = $todo->nextActionDate;
        $calendar = new CalendarController();

        return $calendar->scheduleFromAnotherSource($eventData);
    }
```

when I execute this, I get an error like below

```
Too few arguments to function CalendarModule\Controller\CalendarController::__construct(), 0 passed in D:\laminas\todo-module-integrated\vendor\iss-module\todo-module\src\Process\TodoScheduleProcess.php on line 53 and exactly 4 expected
```

I know that I'm not supposed to call the `CalendarController` directly rather it should be through a `Service`.

**My question is**, how should I create a `Service` in `Todo module` that has the dependency on `Calendar module` and it should interact with `Calendar module` without requiring the involvement of `CalendarController` which has further dependencies?

Comment: Extract the logic from `CalenderController` and put it in a service which can be used by both `CalenderController` and `Todo` module.

Comment: Does that require replicating the google authentication as well? That means its not possible to use a feature of Calendar module by any other module programmatically other than through APIs or replication of code?

Comment: So how about submitting the data as form (hidden fields) to a `Calendar module` action and getting it processed there and then returning the newly generated `eventID` back to `Todo module` maybe through an API. Is it a good practice?

Comment: Duplication smells like something could be extracted and made reusable. So, no, it  should not require duplication. Authentication/authorization should be separated from actual business logic.

Comment: Best practice is the sepraration of concerns. As @arueckauer said, extract the logic into a service. Google authentication should also be a separate class, that only handles authentication. Calling the Google service should also be a separate class. At the end everything should be separated, so that it can be used in every context you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.

Here's how I've implemented it. (May it'll help someone)

In my `Calendar-module`, the logic of adding is separate from `CalendarController` and its called `AddProcess`, this is how I add an event from the controller. `$result = $this->addProcess->execute($this->params()->fromPost());`. The Google authentication is being handled through a separate service `CalendarClientService`. All my processes access this service to authenticate as below and then get executed.

```
$client = $this->calendarClientService->getClient();
if (!$this->calendarClientService->authenticateClient($client)) {
    return ["error" => "authentication", "url" => filter_var($client->createAuthUrl(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)];
}
```

Now I've created a new service in `Calendar-module` as below where I just called `AddProcess` and passed it the new `eventData`.

```
class CalendarService
{
    protected AddProcess $addProcess;

    public function __construct(AddProcess $addProcess)
    {
        $this->addProcess = $addProcess;
    }

    public function scheduleAsEvent($eventData)
    {
        $eventData["startDateTime"] = Carbon::parse($eventData["startDateTime"])->format("Y-m-d\TH:i");
        $eventData["endDateTime"] = Carbon::parse($eventData["endDateTime"])->format("Y-m-d\TH:i");

        return $this->addProcess->execute($eventData);
    }
}
```

Then from my `Todo-module`, I access this service as below

````
namespace TodoModule\Process;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Google\Exception;
use Laminas\Cache\Exception\ExceptionInterface;
use Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use CalendarModule\Service\CalendarService;
use TodoModule\Service\CrmApiService;

class TodoScheduleProcess extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected int $todoID;

    protected CalendarService $calendarService;

    public function __construct(CalendarService $calendarService)
    {
        $this->calendarService = $calendarService;
    }

    public function execute(): array
    {
        $todo = json_decode((new CrmApiService())->getTodo($this->getTodoId()));
        $eventData["summary"] = $todo->title;
        $eventData["description"] = $todo->content;
        $eventData["startDateTime"] = $todo->nextActionDate;
        $eventData["endDateTime"] = $todo->nextActionDate;

        return $this->calendarService->scheduleAsEvent($eventData);
    }

    public function getTodoId()
    {
        return $this->todoID;
    }

    public function setTodoId($id)
    {
        $this->todoID = $id;
    }
}```
````